# CSS centering DIV when lines is broken

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I'm trying to set content of .container when lines is broken. I have no idea how to use at the same time float:left and center. Both exlusive i think.

```css
div.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
}

div.floatfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

div.item {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container floatfix">
  <div class="item">First Item</div>
  <div class="item">Another Item</div>
  <div class="item">Just Another Item</div>
  <div class="item">Middle Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Last Item</div>
  <div class="item">Realy Last Item</div>
</div>
```

I want to get effect like below
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` on your items.

Then you can modify your container's style with the following:

- `margin: auto`: center it in the page
- `text-align: auto`: center its content
- `width: ...px`: limit the width

That gives you:

```css
div.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

div.floatfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

div.item {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container floatfix">
  <div class="item">First Item</div>
  <div class="item">Another Item</div>
  <div class="item">Just Another Item</div>
  <div class="item">Middle Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Last Item</div>
  <div class="item">Realy Last Item</div>
</div>
```